# Android Native App Designing Frameworks

Tags: android, web-applications

What I am trying to do might not be quite difficult but I am confusing myself. I am trying to build an app only for Android that will play videos for my company.

As I am not an native Android developer what I did is using html, jquery and phonegap to create and bundle my app as a web view which will help the end user installing the app instead of going to a URL and then open it.

Now here the challenge starts for me, I am looking for touch optimized design which should look like a native app. I can use twitter bootstrap , foundation or any other CSS framework to make my design responsive. I also know how to make ajax based animated page loading which will help me in preventing complete page load.

The real issue: is css the only and right way to design a mobile app? Does apps like Facebook , Youtube also make use of Css to design their native apps?

I do not want to use jquery mobile because I simply don't like their design patterns.

Again, my question might seems to be foolish. What I want to use are industry standard tools to build my app, even if I have to dig into Android tutorials and learn it from scratch.

Any help ,links or guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native apps do typically not use HTML/CSS, and instead use the widgets etc provided by the platform. That's what native means. Facebook recently switched from a web view/HTML5 implementation to native (at least on Android).

Comment: Ok i was not sure about the widgets , do you have any links to point me the right way ( Though i am browsing google to get something useful )

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but have you looked at http://developer.android.com/index.html?